# Include libqtforandroid.so or libqtforandroidGL.so in package?

Tags: android, c++, mingw, qt-creator, qt6

I try to run the QT C++ usb debugger on an Android smartphone, altough there is a compilation error (on the screenshot #1). The downloaded version of QTCreator is 4.14.2 with Qt 6.0.3 MinGw 64-bit.

[image: Error image]

[image: settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it's solved, you just need to delete the existing ".user" file from the project directory and choose your Android kit when you open up the project again.